# Hyperledger Fabric set-up download specific platform binaries permissions error OSX

Tags: bash, macos, unix, terminal, hyperledger-fabric

I am attempting to install and run Hyperledger Fabric on OSX as per [the docs](http://fabric-rtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html), however I am running into permission errors when downloading the platform specific binaries by executing the command `sudo curl -sSL <URL to binaries> | bash` which downloads a script to retrieve the platform binaries

> cryptogen
>   configtxgen
>   and configtxlator

Even though I use sudo I am still receiving

```
Erics-MacBook-Pro:fabric-samples EricMcEvoy$ sudo curl -sSL <URL to binaries I can't post in SO> | bash

Password:
    ===> Downloading platform binaries

      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0


tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/docker-compose-e2e.yaml: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/install: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/install/get-docker-images.sh: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/base: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/base/docker-compose-base.yaml: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/base/peer-base.yaml: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/channel-artifacts: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/channel-artifacts/.gitkeep: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/chaincode: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/chaincode/go: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/chaincode/go/marbles02: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/chaincode/go/marbles02/marbles_chaincode.go: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02.go: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/end-to-end.rst: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/crypto-config.yaml: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/scripts: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/scripts/script.sh: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/generateArtifacts.sh: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/configtx.yaml: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/network_setup.sh: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/docker-compose-e2e-template.yaml: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/download-dockerimages.sh: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/docker-compose-cli.yaml: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: release/darwin-amd64: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: release/darwin-amd64/bin: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
```

I have tried enabling root user in System preferences Users & Groups, running the script myself in my own .sh file and still permissions denied.

Is there anyway to disable this feature?
Is there anyway to enable sudo for the whole script?

Many thanks quite new to this

Comment: First, why are you trying to run this as sudo? Secondly, you have somehow come across a stale version of the docs. The correct version is http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Which folder are you running this command from?

Comment: I ran as sudo because I was receiving mkdir permission denied when running the curl command on it's own. Thank you for pointing me to the latest docs, this has pulled down more recent images but I still have the same permissions issue when running curl with the new URL. I am running the command inside the GOPATH at /Users/McEvoy/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples

Comment: can you post output of "ls -lsa /Users/McEvoy/go/src/github.com/hyperledger"?

Comment: `/Users/McEvoy/go/src/github.com/hyperledger
Erics-MacBook-Pro:hyperledger EricMcEvoy$ ls -lsa
total 8
0 drwxr-xr-x   4 root  staff   136  1 Aug 20:13 .
0 drwxr-xr-x   3 root  staff   102 27 Jul 16:39 ..
0 drwxr-xr-x  14 root  staff   476  1 Aug 20:22 fabric-samples
8 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root  staff  1364  1 Aug 20:14 script.sh`

Comment: seems like you ran the git clone as root (sudo) when you cloned fabric-samples or when you created the go/src/github.com/hyperledger directory into which you cloned fabric-samples (as root). You may want to start over and use your account to create all this content.

Comment: it might be more expedient to work through this on the Hyperledger chat https://chat.hyperledger.org/ Artem is `at c0rwin` and I'm `at cbf` but there are a bunch of people there who can help.

Comment: @christo4ferris yeah it seems you're right. I removed everything and just cloned normally again and it's working. Thanks for your help everyone, resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you ran the git clone as root (sudo) when you cloned fabric-samples or when you created the go/src/github.com/hyperledger directory into which you cloned fabric-samples (as root). You may want to start over and use your account to create all this content.